# Does Nativescript or React Native support ok google and siri?

Tags: react-native, nativescript, siri

I am starting out on building an app and have been looking around for further information on integrating siri and ok google using either Nativescript or React Native, but have not been able to find much online. Can anyone if these are compatible and if you have any experience / links on how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: check their site for js or web api , i am sure google have one

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google (Google Assistant Integration) is supported by both NativeScript and React Native.

If you're just interested in Speech Recognition, you can use:
https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-speech-recognition

Otherwise, e.g. for NativeScript you can simply call any Native (ObjectiveC / Java) method, use existing libraries, etc.